# gets 404 error while runing SOAP UI in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Im trying to execute soapUI script in Jmeter but i am getting response as 404 in sampler result and Response Body is empty.

I have added SOAPAction and content type as well in header manager.

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: I got this answer from developer when i asked which method(GET/POST) it is ? It is SOAP Based Web Service. There is no such Get/Post Method here.

Everything is working based on XML Payload Request

Answer (score 0):

Soap uses POST not GET HTTP method.

Ensure you add a [Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) with correct **SOAPAction** header.

Use SOAP UI to generate the call from WSDL this will give you:

- the URL
- the Request Body
- the correct headers

Alternatively, what you can do to be sure to send same data as SoapUI is to use JMeter Recording template, and put JMeter as a proxy of SoapUI then call WS from SoapUI, this will be recorded by JMeter

Comment: Thank you UBIK LOAD PACK...But if i give GET i am getting jmeter response as same as when i open the WSDL URL in browser

Comment: yes but to call the WS it's not the WSDL url, it's another URL that uses POST

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)  means `Not Found` which basically indicates that you're hitting the wrong URL in JMeter.

Switch to "Raw" mode in the SoapUI and you will be able to see the correct URL and headers you will need to supply:

[image]

Also be aware that you can just record the request(s) from SoapUI using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

1. Prepare JMeter for recording, the fastest and easiest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - from JMeter's main menu choose File -> Templates -> Recording and click "Create"

     [image]
   - Expand HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image]
2. Prepare SoapUI for recording

   - from SoapUI main menu choose File -> Preferences -> Proxy
   - configure it to match the JMeter settings
   - click "Proxy" button in SoapUI main toolbar

   [image]

More information: [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

Comment: I am facing the same problem and trying to do the same but when i cahnge the proxy settings it does not run the request in soapui